# I'm replacing the under-sink pipes, and I'm confused what connector this is

Tags: plumbing, pipe, sink, copper

I'm replacing the pipe under the sink after it cracked.

I thought I had figured everything out, but the connector I got doesn't fit due to this non-threaded copper bit above the threads, is it something I can remove with pliers, or should I try to unscrew further down and replace it from there?

New pipe is 3/8" COMP to 1/2" FIP

[image: under-sink pipe]

[image: connector of new pipe 3/8th COMP]

Answer (score 1):

That's a flared fitting (see: [flared fitting copper](https://www.google.com/search?q=flared%20fitting%20copper)).  They are meant to accept the end of a piece of copper pipe, flared using a special tool.  Looking at the picture, it does seem that you might be able to replace that part under the sink with a brass fitting (see: [brass male-male pipe nipple](https://www.google.com/search?q=brass%20pipe%20male-male%20nipple) ) that will properly accept your hose, but it might be difficult, given the corrosion.